# Monitor continuously in my directory using Inotify in c language

Tags: c, inotify

I am trying to monitor continuously in my directory to know when a file is created, deleted, modified using Inotify in C language.

I have done like below :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/inotify.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    #define EVENT_SIZE  (sizeof(struct inotify_event))
    #define BUF_LEN     (1024 * (EVENT_SIZE + 16))

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int length, i = 0;
    int fd;
    int wd;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    fd = inotify_init();

    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("inotify_init");
    }

    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, ".",
        IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);
    length = read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);

    if (length < 0) {
        perror("read");
    }

    while (i < length) {
        struct inotify_event *event =
            (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];
        if (event->len) {
            if (event->mask & IN_CREATE) {
                printf("The file %s was created.\n", event->name);
            } else if (event->mask & IN_DELETE) {
                printf("The file %s was deleted.\n", event->name);
            } else if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
                printf("The file %s was modified.\n", event->name);
            }
        }
        i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
    }

    (void) inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
    (void) close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

but here after a new file is created, it is immediately coming out, but I am trying watch continuously what is happening in my directory.

Comment: You only read from the descriptor once.  You need to read repeatedly.

Comment: need to write read() in while (1)